# String formatting for decimal places and thousands

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to represent the number 2.3421 as 2.34 but my current formatting shows it as 02.34

If I had the number 1342.323 I would want to show this as 1,342.32

If I had 0.23 this would be shown as 0.23.

What do I change my format string to achieve this? I have:

"{0:0,0.00}"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `#` where a number is optional instead of `0`:

```
"{0:#,0.00}"
```

See [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) on MSDN:

> "#" | Digit placeholder
>
> Replaces the pound sign with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.

Comment: Yes, but 'optional number' is 'optional leading zeroes'

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Yes, noticed his last example and updated my answer.

Comment: @user1107474 - `0.ToString("#,0.00");` returns "0.00" for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
{0:#,##0.00}
```

1342.323 should then be 1,342.32