# convert formatted decimal string with thousand seperator

Tags: c#, .net

I could not find answer which combines the two here.

I am getting from the database for example 8120.349 and looking to convert this to two decimal and thousand seperator. so ideal output string I am looking for here is 8,120.35

Currently I am converting to two decimal using

```
MaxValue.ToString("F2") //maxvalue is decimal
```

this outputs me 8120.35

tried adding this for thousand seperator after looking at few answers.

```
String.Format("{0:n}", MaxValue.ToString("F2"))
```

this still gives me same output.

any ideas here?

Comment: See [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: why downvote?? whoever has downvoted..

Comment: possible duplicate of [String formatting for decimal places and thousands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941219/string-formatting-for-decimal-places-and-thousands)

Comment: I'm guessing someone thought it was easy to find on google. I'd agree with that but at least you showed some attempt at solving the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `MaxValue.ToString("N2")`

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uEBlPA

Answer (score 1):

You should use : [Standard Numeric("N") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#NFormatString)

```
double number = 8120.349;

var stringFormatted = number.ToString("n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use a hand made formatting,

```
string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", 8120.349)
```